# jQuery code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery, but not new to programming. Still I cannot find out whats wrong with this simple piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.footer').click(function() {
        $('.footer').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

It won't work on my own website, but it does work when I use codeacademy. 
What is wrong with this?

Edit: Awhile ago I made this question. It was a simple thing I did not understand back then when I started jQuery. The solution was to import the library first before taking any other actions in javascript. The code did work in codeacedemy because the library is automatically imported. This is very important to know for each beginner, but this piece of infomation is everywhere on the web.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library correctly?

Comment: Is there any error on the javascript console?

Comment: If you know that the code itself works but not in a different context (your website), shouldn't you provide more information about the context? How are we supposed to help you otherwise? You should definitely read http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: The code you've posted is fine. Do you have a `.footer` div? Are you including jQuery? Are you getting any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: Note that if you want to specifically fade out the .footer element you clicked, then you want `$(this).fadeOut('slow')`

Comment: Also note that that 'it doesn't work' is never enough information for someone to fix the problem.

Comment: Its working fine for me... see this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/58/ ...

Comment: You need to show us some more code, like your HTML...

Comment: Why would anyone mark this question down. So many idiots on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few checkpoints...

Make sure you include the jQuery library, inside your `<head>`.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If that's fine, do you have an element with the class `.footer`? If not, is it an `ID`? In that case, you need to add this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footer').click(function() {
        $('#footer').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Actually, this can be done in another best way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footer').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for helping. It seemed it was working, but for some reason it is taking very long for my server to interpret the code, so this was not a jQuery problem. Still, my personal appreciations for helping me out.